# Navigate to URL in different window

Tags: visualforce

How can I open URL from link on vf page in a new window, and existing window should be automatically closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can open new window by user **target="_blank"** attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools.com!</a> 
<p>If you set the target attribute to "_blank", the link will open in a new browser window/tab.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But you cant close the browser window that you have not open with in your case the VF page.

So here is workaround that is not browser safe.

```
<button type="button"  onclick="window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();">Discard</button>
```